# Handle interrupts with same priority

Tags: interrupt, avr

If I have a set of peripherals in an AVR microcontroller with equal priority, does the microcontroller use round-robin as a suitable arbitration mechanism for interrupting the sub system?

Or else, how can it manage interrupts with the same priority that happen at same time?

Comment: atymic's comment is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

For example "classical" AVR microcontrollers have simple one-level interrupt controller. That means, when interrupt is running, interrupt flag in SREG is cleared, thus blocking any other interrupt from running. IRET instruction enables this flag back again, and
after one instruction from the main code is executed, next interrupt is ready to be executed.

When several interrupt requests are asserted simultaneously, then only the one with the lowest interrupt vector address is chosen.

For example, refer to the [ATMega328P datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) (section 6.7 *Reset and Interrupt Handling*, page 15):

> The lower the address the higher is the priority level.

Thus, if interrupt request flag is not cleared, or reasserted before return of the interrupt handler, the same interrupt will run again, and interrupt handlers with higher interrupt vector addresses might be never executed.

But in the newest versions of the architecture there is a more advanced interrupt controller, which allows to enable Round Robin scheduling, and assign to one of the interrupts a higher level (allowing it to be executed even if another interrupt handler is running).

For example in ATmega3208 (refer to [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/megaAVR0-series-Family-Data-Sheet-DS40002015B.pdf), section 12. *CPU Interrupt Controller*):

> All interrupt vectors other than NMI are assigned to priority level 0 (normal) by default. The user may override this by assigning one of these vectors as a high priority vector. The device will have many normal priority vectors, and some of these may be pending at the same time. Two different scheduling schemes are available to choose which of the pending normal priority interrupts to service first: Static and round robin

So, **the answer is**: carefully read the datasheet on the part you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

Section 9 of the ATmega328PB datasheet is entitled "AVR CPU Core" and it says:

> All interrupts have a separate interrupt vector in the interrupt vector table.
>   The interrupts have priority in accordance with their interrupt vector position. The lower the interrupt vector address, the higher the priority.